# What is a good adjective that means 'Of or pertaining to a bed'?

Tags: single-word-requests

So in this [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/388654/is-there-a-name-for-the-truncated-bedspread-that-some-hotels-put-on-the-bottom-2), suppose I wanted to call a bed scarf/valance as a/an 'X drapery', where X is the word I'm looking for, which should mean 'of or pertaining to a bed' (or any place which is lied upon to rest, really). Is there such a word?

Comment: I think you are looking for bed, *bed drapery*.

Comment: While a noun adjective does work, I'm on the lookout for a pure adjective form. +1 for a sensible suggestion though.

Comment: Anyways, if you don't want to use "bed", I've given the answer commonly used in marketing materials!  Enjoy!  :)

Comment: I'm aware it's obvious, and that it works. I've clearly acknowledged it as well. I just put up the question to perhaps gain more vocabulary of a word/adjective form that might exist. Is that so wrong? :) 

There are tons of adjective forms I've learnt of from this website, and this question happens to be framed in a similar vein. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

English commonly forms closed compounds in which *bed* is the attributive noun: *bedsheet, bedstead, bedlinens, bedclothes, bedskirt, bedspread,* even *bedbug*. German follows a similar pattern: *Betttuch/Bettlacken*, ’bedsheet’, *Bettzeug*, ‘bedlinens’, or *Bettwanze*, ‘bedbug’.

While neither of these two Germanic languages has felt the slightest need to form an adjective from *bed*, there was one readily available in (new) Latin: the scientific name for a bedbug, Cimex lectularius, the second term formed from *lectula*, dim. of *lectus*, ‘bed’. You can see this etymology behind French *lit* or Italian *letto*, ‘bed’.

This could have yielded **lectular* in English, had anyone bothered to coin the word. In the late 18th c. there was yet another attempt to enrich medical jargon with a Latin-derived term, [*lectual*](https://archive.org/stream/oed6aarch#page/n182/mode/1up), to mean ‘bed-ridden/bedfast’, but it‘s easy to see why that particular coinage never got off the ground: far too many English words derived from *lectus*, the past participle of *legere*, ‘to read’ (*lecture, lection, lectern,* etc.), and while reading in bed may be pleasurable, trying to form an adjective from *lectula* or *lectus* ‘bed’ is etymologically confusing.

So, no, there is no adjective form of *bed* in English, and the usual sources of new coinages — Greek, as you've seen in another answer here, or Latin, either directly or through French — were not conducive to fashioning a new word for which no one has felt any particular need — at least until now.

Comment: So the 'most reasonable' one would have to be 'lectular'?

Comment: _Lectular_ might have been a logical choice, but it isn't an English word, also because of all the "reading" _lectus_ words. The main thing is that there's no need for it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer is "bedding".

As in "We sell bedding".

Or in your example, something like "a bedding drapery".

Or something like "We sell every bedding article, from pillows to poufs to drapery and even mosquito nets and sleeping bags."

---

Note too that simply

> "bed drapery"

does make perfect, absolute, sense and sounds natural.

(This is no more unusual than saying "car parts" or "dog biscuits".)

(It's totally commonplace in English that you can use, basically, any part of speech as another - you can turn pretty much any word in to a verb or adjective or adverb. In this case it is totally natural-sounding. You are mistaken to think it's not a "real" adjective - just saw your comments above!)

Comment: I never said it isn't a 'real' adjective. I even said that it worked. I was merely curious to learn of a non-nounadjective form, if any.

Comment: sure, sorry if I slightly misunderstood you.  anyway "bedding" is a great word here, often used in that industry just as in your example.

Comment: Agreed. I'll keep it in mind. +1

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a common adjective which ultimately derives from "pertaining to a bed", but I think it will surprise you, and ultimately not be useful for your context:

#### Clinical

Per [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/clinic?ref=etymonline_crossreference):

> 1620s, "bedridden person, one confined to his bed by sickness," from French *clinique* (17c.), from Latin *clinicus* "physician that visits patients in their beds," from Greek *klinike* (*techne*) "(practice) at the sickbed," **from *klinikos* "of the bed," from *kline* "bed, couch, that on which one lies,"** from suffixed form of PIE root **klei*- "to lean."

To find a more suitable term, you might look for more words ultimately derived from Greek *kline* (like, for example, *incline*).

Comment: So something like, 'klinikian' or 'klinian'?

Comment: No, *klinikos* is Greek.  The English analog is precisely *clinical*.  You'll need to find other already-established (i.e. recorded in reputable dictionaries) words which also derive (ultimately) from*kline*, but have retained or developed a closer relationship to the "bed" meaning.

Comment: Fair enough.  I was thinking about using it as a derivative similar to thalasso-, from thálassa.

Comment: @Kugelblitz - to be clear, it is utterly inconceivable you would ever use this for your use case, in speech or writing.  (Not to say it isn't a fantastic answer.)

Comment: No idea why it was downvoted lol. It's insightful.

Comment: @Kugelblitz You want [insightful](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bedniss)? ;)

Comment: Good lord haha XD